# Can I write a kubernetes controller in Nodejs instead of go?

Tags: node.js, go, kubernetes

Looking into it for making awesome api things, but I don't know Go yet. I see there are generators for go, but I'd rather use a more familiar language at first. Is this possible or should I start learning Go?

Comment: Have you had any success? I've no clue how I can create a controller using ```NodeJS```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client libraries for Kubernetes are available in many languages. See here for examples: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/